# Show username and user id on Label after Login Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a school project. One of my ideas is to after the Login Form the Main Form will show on a label the user connected and the RM (user code basically), but i don't know how to get the Username and RM from the Login Screen and get the RM from the database.

Login Screen Code:

```
public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ROCHA-PC\SQLSERVER2014;Initial Catalog=Usuarios;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) from users where usuario = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND senha = '" + textBox2.Text + "'" , con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            this.Hide();
            frmTelaInicial nform = new frmTelaInicial();
            nform.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro ao logar");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

How can I get the current user connected and show it on the label?

Comment: Side-note: Your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should look up how to use "parameterized queries".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the constructor of the main window and add the parameters you want for example

step 1)
 here pass the parameters you want

```
 frmTelaInicial nform = new frmTelaInicial(LoggedUseName,RM);
```

step 2)
at the constructor of the frmTelaInicial add the two parameters like below

```
    public frmTelaInicial(string LoggedUserName,string RM)
            {



//here you have the passed values

              }
```

step 3)

add two labels  on the frmTelaInicial window and update their values with the passed  values LoggedUserName and RM

Comment: At the beginning a was confused but now I understand, thank you so much.